# Display XMLGregorianCalendar Date on JSP page using struts-tags

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, date, web, struts2

I am getting Date details in the format of `XMLGregorianCalendar` and I try to display it on the JSP page using struts tags:

```
<td><s:date name="issuedDate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
```

But this date filed display nothing on the JSP page, could anybody help me to know how to get is displayed on the JSP page. I am getting these date objects of this type from a web service.

Comment: I don't think `s:date` can format an `XMLGregorianCalendar` so you will probably need a getter that returns output of the [`toGregorianCalender`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar()) method in your bean/action.

Comment: The format is not corresponding to the formatter.

Comment: @RomanC: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @AleksandrM That what OP is said `in the format of XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Comment: @RomanC: So you think this is actually a `String` object not `XMLGregorianCalendar`?

Comment: @AleksandrM No, I think it's `Date` in the format of XMLGregorianCalendar.

Comment: @RomanC: If it is `Date` then `<s:date>` tag should render it.

Comment: @AleksandrM That's the question.

Comment: @RomanC: If it is web service then dates have probably `XMLGregorianCalendar` type not `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `issuedDate` object is `XMLGregorianCalendar` type. You can call `toGregorianCalendar()` method of `XMLGregorianCalendar` right in `<s:date>` tag.

```
<td><s:date name="issuedDate.toGregorianCalendar()" format="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
```

Comment: No point in downvoting an asnwer. I assume that OP object type is `XMLGregorianCalendar` and if it is not then I will correct my answer.

Comment: thanks Aleksandr M, it worked for me, I have up voted your answer, i didn't down-vote it, pls up-vote my question too, i think it is not a useless question :)

Comment: @KItis: Not useless at all. Glad I helped you. :)